# Data Import From Excel excluding columns

Tags: r, excel

I am importing a large dataset from Excel with R Studio. Once I import, the dataset is missing the last 50 or so columns. Is there anyway I can force R to keep all the columns? Or is there a quicker way to eliminate the less useful columns than individually clicking skip on each column I can leave out?

Comment: How are you importing the data and how many columns does the original have?

Comment: can you also provide the code that you use for importing the excel file?

Comment: Also, as it sounds like you're using the GUI menu to do the importing, what version of RStudio are you using? Older versions used to only show the first 100 columns in the data viewer, so if it's just that, update your RStudio version.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the openxlsx package? See p. 44 of https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx/openxlsx.pdf for the read.xlsx command, which lets you specify which rows and columns you want to import.